# set cell value as hyperlink in mxGraph

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mxgraph

I am working on the mxgraph and in the graph page when we select a cell and gives a value it should be displayed as hyperlink only. But when i used html,anchor tag or in other ways, the entire code displays in the cell as a text. Even if i try to input the value dynamically also it displays as text.

```html
  var Element123 = "<html><a href=''/Graph/Graph/' + globals.getProjID() + '/' + newValue +' '>' "+ selctedItem +" </a></html>"
            this.graph.labelChanged(cell, Element123, evt);
            this.graph.getModel().endUpdate();
        }
```

here the newValue is the ID of the selected option from the dropdown.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how i added a click event for the cell value in mxGraph. -

```js
mxEvent.addListener(name, "click", function () { } );
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to enable HTML in labels. You can do this for all cells by calling `graph.setHtmlLabels(true)`. Or you can override the following method to decide per cell:

```
/**
 * Function: isHtmlLabel
 * 
 * Returns true if the label must be rendered as HTML markup. The default
 * implementation returns <htmlLabels>.
 * 
 * Parameters:
 * 
 * cell - <mxCell> whose label should be displayed as HTML markup.
 */
mxGraph.prototype.isHtmlLabel = function(cell)
{
    return this.isHtmlLabels();
};
```